# Download multiple files simultaneously from FTP using FluentFTP

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, ftp, fluentftp

I'm using FluentFTP for connecting, downloading, etc. from FTP
https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/wiki

I would like to download files simultaneously from List. There is no problem downloading them one by one.

This is how my code looks like:

Downloading function:

```
public async Task<bool> DownloadFileAsync(string RemoteUrl, string AppName, Progress<FtpProgress> progress = null)
    {
        return await Task.Run(async() =>
        {

            using (FileStream read = new FileStream("settings.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                if (ftpClient.IsConnected)
                {
                    if (File.Exists("settings.xml"))
                    {
                        Information info = (Information)xs.Deserialize(read);
                    
                        if (Directory.Exists(info.Downloads))
                        {
                            bool DownloadFinished = await ftpClient.DownloadFileAsync(info.Downloads + "\\" + AppName, RemoteUrl, FtpLocalExists.Overwrite, FtpVerify.Retry, progress);
                            if (DownloadFinished == true)
                            {
                                loger.LogWrite("File " + RemoteUrl + " downloaded succesfully.");
                                //read.Dispose();
                                return true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                loger.LogWrite("File" + RemoteUrl + " download failed.");
                                //read.Dispose();
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            loger.LogWrite("Could not locate folder " + info.Downloads + " downloading terminated.");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("settings.xml file is missing.");
                        loger.LogWrite("settings.xml file is missing.");
                        read.Dispose();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    loger.LogWrite("FTP Client is not connected could not download: " + RemoteUrl);
                    read.Dispose();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

How I fill the list:

```
Arta_Variables.ArtaSoftware.Add(new Software() { RemoteUrl = "Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/Adobe_Reader.exe", SoftwareName = "Adobe_Reader.exe", FileExistsOnRemoteUrl = null, Downloaded = null });
```

This is how downloading them one by one:

```
if(Arta_Variables.DAAOChecked == false)
{
    if (CheckFinished == true)
    {
        using (FileStream read = new FileStream("settings.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Information));
            Information info = (Information)xs.Deserialize(read);

            AddBlackLine("");
            AddBlackLine("Downloading all available files.");
            AddBlackLine("");

            foreach (Software software1 in ArtaChosenSW)
            {

                string item = software1.SoftwareName;
                int index = ArtaChosenSW.FindIndex(p => p.SoftwareName == item);

                if (software1.FileExistsOnRemoteUrl == true)
                {
                    AddBlackLine("Downloading " + software1.SoftwareName);

                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        DWGProgressLab.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        DP_ProgressPercentage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    });

                    Progress<FtpProgress> prog = new Progress<FtpProgress>(x =>
                    {
                        int ConvertedInt = (int)x.Progress;
                        DP_ProgressPercentage.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => DP_ProgressPercentage.Content = ConvertedInt + "%"));
                    });

                    bool DWFinished = await ftp.DownloadFileAsync(software1.RemoteUrl, software1.SoftwareName, prog);

                    if (DWFinished == true)
                    {
                        AddGreenLine("Download of " + software1.SoftwareName + " succesfull.");
                        ArtaChosenSW[index].Downloaded = true;
                        ArtaChosenSW[index].LocalUrl = info.Downloads;

                        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            DWGProgressLab.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                            DP_ProgressPercentage.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                        });

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddRedLine("Download of " + software1.SoftwareName + " failed");
                        ArtaChosenSW[index].FileExistsOnRemoteUrl = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ArtaChosenSW[index].FileExistsOnRemoteUrl = true;
                    AddBlackLine("File " + software1.SoftwareName + " did not found on ftp. Could not download.");
                    loger.LogWrite("File " + software1.SoftwareName + " did not found on ftp. Could not download.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My try for simultaneous download:

```
foreach(Software software in ArtaChosenSW)
{
    var tasks = ArtaChosenSW.Select(c => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ftp.DownloadFileAsync(c.RemoteUrl, c.SoftwareName))).ToArray();
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
```

Sadly what it does it's creating blank files in local url with 0kb but no downloading is happening.

I'm not much experienced in async programming so I'll be glad for all answers or some better approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using one `FtpClient` instance for all your transfers.

The `FtpClient` represents one connection to an FTP server. FTP protocol does not allow multiple parallel transfers over one connection. You have to open a new connection for every parallel transfer.

For an example of an implementation, see [Download multiple files concurrently from FTP using FluentFTP with a maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66241158/850848).

Answer (score 0):

Taking your code from the answer you posted, this should handle multiple downloads without any thread-pool or `Task` wrapper overhead.

```
public async Task DownloadMultipleFilesConcurrentFromFTP(int NumberOfConnections, string AppName, string RemoteUrl)
{
    var downloadTasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfConnections; i++){
        downloadTasks.Add(DownloadFile(AppName, RemoteUrl));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);
}
 
public async Task DownloadFile(string AppName, string RemoteUrl)
{
    var ftp = new FtpClient(FTPHost, networkCredential);
    ftp.ConnectTimeout = ConnectTimeout;
    ftp.SocketPollInterval = SocketPollInterval;
    ftp.ReadTimeout = ReadTimeout;
    ftp.DataConnectionConnectTimeout = DataConnectionConnectTimeout;
    ftp.DataConnectionReadTimeout = DataConnectionReadTimeout;
    await ftp.ConnectAsync();
    if (ftp.IsConnected)
    {
        using (FileStream read = new FileStream("settings.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            if (ftp.IsConnected == true)
            {
                if (File.Exists("settings.xml"))
                {
                    Information info = (Information)xs.Deserialize(read);
                    if (Directory.Exists(info.Downloads))
                    {
                        await ftp.DownloadFileAsync(info.Downloads + "\\" + AppName, RemoteUrl, FtpLocalExists.Overwrite, FtpVerify.Retry);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It creates a single `Task` for each download, and then calls `Task.WhenAll` on the list of tasks to wait for all files to complete before returning.

I haven't modified any of your file handling code, but you should consider using `async` versions of your calls there also, as accessing the file system using blocking calls can cause responsiveness issues.

Answer (score -1):

Based on @Martin Prikryl answer i created new function for concurrent downloads:

Works flawlesly:

```
public async Task DownloadMultipleFilesConcurrentFromFTP(int NumberOfConnections, string AppName, string RemoteUrl)
{
    await Task.Run(async() =>
    {
        NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(FTPUsername, FTPPassword);
        List<FtpClient> ftpClients = new List<FtpClient>();

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfConnections; i++)
        {
            ftpClients.Add(new FtpClient(FTPHost, networkCredential));
            foreach(FtpClient ftp in ftpClients)
            {
                ftp.ConnectTimeout = ConnectTimeout;
                ftp.SocketPollInterval = SocketPollInterval;
                ftp.ReadTimeout = ReadTimeout;
                ftp.DataConnectionConnectTimeout = DataConnectionConnectTimeout;
                ftp.DataConnectionReadTimeout = DataConnectionReadTimeout;
                ftp.Connect();
                if (ftp.IsConnected)
                {
                    using (FileStream read = new FileStream("settings.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        if(ftp.IsConnected == true)
                        {
                            if (File.Exists("settings.xml"))
                            {
                                Information info = (Information)xs.Deserialize(read);
                                if (Directory.Exists(info.Downloads))
                                {
                                    await ftp.DownloadFileAsync(info.Downloads + "\\" + AppName, RemoteUrl, FtpLocalExists.Overwrite, FtpVerify.Retry);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now i just need figure out how return download progress of all files.

Comment: This would work better if you didn't use `Task.Run`, and instead created a plain `Task` for each download job, and awaited them all with `Task.WhenAll`.  This would allow you to report progress directly from within the download `Task`, and helps avoid multi-threading issues.

Comment: You should also probably await `ftp.ConnectAsync()`, instead of calling `ftp.Connect()`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I thought this line is creating  task for each ftpclient:

var tasks = ArtaChosenSW.Select(c => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ftp.DownloadMultipleFilesConcurrentFromFTP(ArtaChosenSW.Count, c.RemoteUrl, c.SoftwareName))).ToArray();

Comment: It _sort of_ does.  It creates a `Task` around the invocation of your anonymous `delegate`, which completes when the thread exits.  Basically, it is wrapper around your code that runs on another thread from the thread pool, which adds some inefficiency and complexity when it comes to interacting with the UI. If you were to do this without using `Task.Run`, it could be done without involving multi threading at all.

Comment: `Task.Run` should only be used in very special circumstances (it always consumes a thread pool thread).  *Usually*, when you see it, you are not doing something correctly. The task factory should be even more rare than `Task.Run`.  It is almost always guaranteed to cause problems.

Comment: @BradleyUffner What about this?

Parallel.ForEach(ArtaChosenSW, x => ftp.DownloadMultipleFilesConcurrentFromFTPAsync(ArtaChosenSW.Count, x.SoftwareName, x.RemoteUrl, prog));

Is this better approach? Or what is the best approach when i need to have active 5 ftp clients which work concurrent but with different attributes and i need read data from them?

Comment: That's still going to use the thread pool, one thread for each download (ish).  Give me a few minutes and I'll write something up for you showing (what i think is) the correct way.

Comment: This should refactor your code in to the pattern I've been describing. https://pastebin.com/MqUnWtRv

Comment: @BradleyUffner thanks for advice, works flawlesly by this approach. But still cant figure out how to get progress of each download separetely. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62752319/download-progress-of-concurrent-tasks

Comment: It [looks like](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/issues/228) you should create a `Progress` instance for each download, and send it in with the call to `ftp.DownloadFileAsync`.  The `Progress` constructor takes a delegate that is periodically called as blocks are downloaded.

Comment: Revisiting this answer, I do not think anymore it's a good one. First the nesting of `for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfConnections; i++)` and `foreach(FtpClient ftp in ftpClients)`. You end up with 1+2+3+4+...+N connections instead of N connections. – But you never use more then one connection at  time anyway. The code does not do at all what it claims.  + You keep downloading the same file all the time. + Other less important issues, like checking for an existence of a file that you have already opened, etc.