# Download multiple files concurrently from FTP using FluentFTP with a maximum value

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, ftp, fluentftp

I would like to download multiple download files recursively from a FTP Directory, to do this I'm using FluentFTP library and my code is this one:

```
private async Task downloadRecursively(string src, string dest, FtpClient ftp)
{

    foreach(var item in ftp.GetListing(src))
    {
        if (item.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.Directory)
        {
            if (item.Size != 0)
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(dest, item.Name));
                downloadRecursively(Path.Combine(src, item.Name), Path.Combine(dest, item.Name), ftp);
            }
        }
        else if (item.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.File)
        {
            await ftp.DownloadFileAsync(Path.Combine(dest, item.Name), Path.Combine(src, item.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

I know you need one FtpClient per download you want, but how can I make to use a certain number of connections as maximum, I guess that the idea is to create, connect, download and close per every file I find but just having a X number of downloading files at the same time. Also I'm not sure if I should create Task with async, Threads and my biggest problem, how to implement all of this.

Answer from [@Bradley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62763736/14889147) here seems pretty good, but the question does read every file thas has to download from an external file and it doesn't have a maximum concurrent download value so I'm not sure how to apply these both requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

- [`ConcurrentBag` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1) to implement a connection pool;
- [`Parallel` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel) to parallelize the operation;
- [`ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) to limit number of the concurrent threads.

```
var clients = new ConcurrentBag<FtpClient>();

var opts = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxConnections };
Parallel.ForEach(files, opts, file =>
{
    file = Path.GetFileName(file);

    string thread = $"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}";
    if (!clients.TryTake(out var client))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{thread} Opening connection...");
        client = new FtpClient(host, user, pass);
        client.Connect();
        Console.WriteLine($"{thread} Opened connection {client.GetHashCode()}.");
    }

    string remotePath = sourcePath + "/" + file;
    string localPath = Path.Combine(destPath, file);
    string desc =
        $"{thread}, Connection {client.GetHashCode()}, " +
        $"File {remotePath} => {localPath}";
    Console.WriteLine($"{desc} - Starting...");
    client.DownloadFile(localPath, remotePath);
    Console.WriteLine($"{desc} - Done.");

    clients.Add(client);
});

Console.WriteLine($"Closing {clients.Count} connections");
foreach (var client in clients)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Closing connection {client.GetHashCode()}");
    client.Dispose();
}
```

---

Another approach is to start a fixed number of threads with one connection for each and have them pick files from a queue.

For an example of an implementation, see my article for WinSCP .NET assembly:
[Automating transfers in parallel connections over SFTP/FTP protocol](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_parallel_transfers)

---

*A similar question about SFTP:*
*[Processing SFTP files using C# Parallel.ForEach loop not processing downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48833005/850848)*

Comment: +1 for correctly choosing the [rarely useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400133/when-to-use-blockingcollection-and-when-concurrentbag-instead-of-listt/64823123#64823123), and awfully lot misused, `ConcurrentBag<T>` class!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) approach. A `BufferBlock<FtpClient>` is used as a pool of `FtpClient` objects. The recursive enumeration takes a parameter of type `IEnumerable<string>` that holds the segments of one filepath. These segments are combined differently when constructing the local and the remote filepath. As a side effect of invoking the recursive enumeration, the paths of the remote files are sent to an `ActionBlock<IEnumerable<string>>`. This block handles the parallel downloading of the files. Its `Completion` property contains eventually all the exceptions that may have occurred during the whole operation.

```
public static Task FtpDownloadDeep(string ftpHost, string ftpRoot,
    string targetDirectory, string username = null, string password = null,
    int maximumConnections = 1)
{
    // Arguments validation omitted            
    if (!Directory.Exists(targetDirectory))
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(targetDirectory);
    var fsLocker = new object();

    var ftpClientPool = new BufferBlock<FtpClient>();

    async Task<TResult> UsingFtpAsync<TResult>(Func<FtpClient, Task<TResult>> action)
    {
        var client = await ftpClientPool.ReceiveAsync();
        try { return await action(client); }
        finally { ftpClientPool.Post(client); } // Return to the pool
    }

    var downloader = new ActionBlock<IEnumerable<string>>(async path =>
    {
        var remotePath = String.Join("/", path);
        var localPath = Path.Combine(path.Prepend(targetDirectory).ToArray());
        var localDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(localPath);
        lock (fsLocker) Directory.CreateDirectory(localDir);
        var status = await UsingFtpAsync(client =>
            client.DownloadFileAsync(localPath, remotePath));
        if (status == FtpStatus.Failed) throw new InvalidOperationException(
            $"Download of '{remotePath}' failed.");
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maximumConnections,
        BoundedCapacity = maximumConnections,
    });

    async Task Recurse(IEnumerable<string> path)
    {
        if (downloader.Completion.IsCompleted) return; // The downloader has failed
        var listing = await UsingFtpAsync(client =>
            client.GetListingAsync(String.Join("/", path)));
        foreach (var item in listing)
        {
            if (item.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.Directory)
            {
                if (item.Size != 0) await Recurse(path.Append(item.Name));
            }
            else if (item.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.File)
            {
                var accepted = await downloader.SendAsync(path.Append(item.Name));
                if (!accepted) break; // The downloader has failed
            }
        }
    }

    // Move on to the thread pool, to avoid ConfigureAwait(false) everywhere
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // Fill the FtpClient pool
        for (int i = 0; i < maximumConnections; i++)
        {
            var client = new FtpClient(ftpHost);
            if (username != null && password != null)
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            ftpClientPool.Post(client);
        }

        try
        {
            // Enumerate the files to download
            await Recurse(new[] { ftpRoot });
            downloader.Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { ((IDataflowBlock)downloader).Fault(ex); }

        try
        {
            // Await the downloader to complete
            await downloader.Completion;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
            when (downloader.Completion.IsCanceled) { throw; }
        catch { downloader.Completion.Wait(); } // Propagate AggregateException
        finally
        {
            // Clean up
            if (ftpClientPool.TryReceiveAll(out var clients))
                foreach (var client in clients) client.Dispose();
        }
    });
}
```

Usage example:

```
await FtpDownloadDeep("ftp://ftp.test.com", "", @"C:\FtpTest",
    "username", "password", maximumConnections: 10);
```

---

**Note:** The above implementation enumerates the remote directory lazily, following the tempo of the downloading process. If you prefer to enumerate it eagerly, gathering all info available about the remote listings ASAP, just remove the `BoundedCapacity = maximumConnections` configuration from the `ActionBlock` that downloads the files. Be aware that doing so could result in high memory consumption, in case the remote directory has a deep hierarchy of subfolders, containing cumulatively a huge number of small files.

Answer (score 0):

I'd split this into three parts.

1. Recursively build a list of source and destination pairs.
2. Create the directories required.
3. Concurrently download the files.

It's the last part that is slow and should be done in parallel.

Here's the code:

```
private async Task DownloadRecursively(string src, string dest, FtpClient ftp)
{
    /* 1 */
    IEnumerable<(string source, string destination)> Recurse(string s, string d)
    {
        foreach (var item in ftp.GetListing(s))
        {
            if (item.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.Directory)
            {
                if (item.Size != 0)
                {
                    foreach(var pair in Recurse(Path.Combine(s, item.Name), Path.Combine(d, item.Name)))
                    {
                        yield return pair;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (item.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.File)
            {
                yield return (Path.Combine(s, item.Name), Path.Combine(d, item.Name));
            }
        }
    }

    var pairs = Recurse(src, dest).ToArray();
    
    /* 2 */
    foreach (var d in pairs.Select(x => x.destination).Distinct())
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(d);
    }

    /* 3 */
    var downloads =
        pairs
            .AsParallel()
            .Select(x => ftp.DownloadFileAsync(x.source, x.destination))
            .ToArray();
    
    await Task.WhenAll(downloads);
}
```

It should be clean, neat, and easy to reason about code.

Comment: Unless I am wrong, this solution will download all files concurrently. But the OP wants to have only X files downloaded at the same time. Btw PLINQ is not async-friendly.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Sure, I need to add max parallel options thingy. In any case, I'm not using `async` with PLINQ in my code.

Comment: True, it's not a case of an `async void` delegate. The thing is that the `DownloadFileAsync` returns a `Task`, and the PLINQ knows nothing about tasks. So all the tasks created by the `DownloadFileAsync` method are just ignored, they are not `await`ed, and so they become fire-and-forget tasks.

Comment: You cannot run multiple parallel transfers over one `FtpClient` instance by default. You can, if you set `EnableThreadSafeDataConnections`, but then a new connection will be opened for every file transfer, what would be terribly inefficient (particularly when downloading lots of small files).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias  - Yes, but I'm not trying to await them until I have created the final array of tasks. I have cleanly separated PLINQ and `await`.

Comment: Exactly. This is why this solution will download all files concurrently. No concurrency limitation exists.